What is meant by the following statement about cin's unsetf() method?
In chapter 11.2.1 of Bjarne Stroustrup's "Principle and {ractice using C++", he shows the following example:
cin.unsetf(ios::dec);  // don’t assume decimal (so that 0x can mean hex)
cin.unsetf(ios::oct);   // don’t assume octal (so that 12 can mean twelve)
cin.unsetf(ios::hex);  // don’t assume hexadecimal (so that 12 can mean twelve)

So, I played around and wrote the following:
int main()
{
    std::cin.unsetf(std::ios::dec);
    for (int x; std::cin >> x;) std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

Which enables the use of the prefixes 0X and 0 for hex and octal. But when inputting 12, or any other integer which does not have the prefixes above, it is still interpreted as 12. So what does he mean when saying this?

don’t assume hexadecimal (so that 12 can mean twelve)

It seems that doing unsetf for hex and oct does not have an effect.

I'd check out cppreference.com. That said, 12 could be the number of hours on a clock (as base 10), the number of fingers on your hands (as base 8) or the legal age when you become an adult (as base 16). OP, just to clarify, are you familiar with the concept of numbering systems with different bases?

when you use unsetf dec, then 0x12 is 18 and 012 is 10 (and 12 is 12)  https://godbolt.org/z/1M5d7TE57

Can you provide the context of this from the book? I think he's trying to undo any previous settings, in case they changed the default radix.

E.g. if there were a previous cin << ios::dec; then you can't use 0x for hex any more, but he wants to ensure that's allowed.

This is used in code that wants to be able to read numeric input consistently, regardless of any format changes that may have been made earlier in the program. So it turns off all the formats that force input into a specific radix. This reverts input integer processing to the default: numbers beginning with 0x are hex, numbers beginning with 0 are octal, and everything else is decimal.
ios::dec forces input to be decimal, which prevents use of the 0x prefix to enter hexadecimal numbers, so we turn that off. ios::oct forces input to be octal, so 12 would mean ten rather than 12. And ios::hex forces input to be hex, so 12 would mean eighteen.
